# Unable to create Scheduler Pools in EMR using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am fairly new to the concept of Spark Schedulers/Pooling and need to implement the same in one of my Projects. Just in order to understand the concept better, I scribbled the following streaming PySpark Code on my local and executed :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import threading


def do_job(f1, f2):
    df1 = spark.readStream.json(f1)
    df2 = spark.readStream.json(f2)
    df = df1.join(df2, "id", "inner")
    df.writeStream.format("parquet").outputMode("append") \
        .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint" + str(f1) + "/") \
        .option("path", "Data/Sample_Delta_Data/date=A" + str(f1)) \
        .start()

    # outputs.append(df1.join(df2, "id", "inner").count())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Demo") \
        .master("local[4]") \
        .config("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "50B") \
        .config("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR") \
        .config("spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference", "true") \
        .getOrCreate()

    file_prefix = "data_new/data/d"
    jobs = []
    outputs = []

    for i in range(0, 6):
        file1 = file_prefix + str(i + 1)
        file2 = file_prefix + str(i + 2)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=do_job, args=(file1, file2))
        jobs.append(thread)

    for j in jobs:
        j.start()

    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
    # print(outputs)
```

As could be seen above, I am using FAIR Scheduler option and using 'Threading Library' in PySpark  to implement Pooling.

As the matter fact, the above code is creating **pools** on my Local System but when I run the same on AWS EMR cluster, no Pools are getting created.

Am I missing something specific to AWS EMR ?

Suggestions please!

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using threading in pyspark?  It handles executors cores --> [spark threading] for you.  I understand you are new to spark but clearly not new to python.  It's possible I missed a subtly here as streaming isn't my wheelhouse as much as spark is my wheelhouse.

The above code will launch all the work on the driver, and I think you really should read over the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) to better understand how it handles parallelism.  (You want to do the work on executors to really get the power you are looking for.)

With respect, this is how you do thing in python not pyspark/spark code.  You likely are seeing the difference between [client vs cluster](https://blog.knoldus.com/cluster-vs-client-execution-modes-for-a-spark-application/#:%7E:text=Spark%20application%20can%20be%20submitted,get%20started%20within%20the%20client.) code, and that could account for the difference. (It's a typical issues that occurs when coding locally vs in the cluster.)

Comment: Need to implement Pooling so that all Jobs starts at the same time using Round-Robin,